# Send data to IOWebSocketChannel on initial connect request

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `IOWebSocketChannel` and trying to authenticate a user in the `upgrade` server event.

When I try adding another parameter to `IOWebSocketChannel`, I get an error saying there are too many parameters. How can I send auth data on initial socket connection request?

```
final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://localhost:4000');
```

**Server**

```
server.on('upgrade', function(request, socket, head) {
    console.log(request);
});
```

Comment: What other parameter are you trying to add? What does the code that shows the error look like. Remember that the other parameters of `.connect()` are optional, so you have to use their names, e.g. `.connect(url, headers: {})`

Comment: @RichardHeap Oh, that was the issue, I didn't add the name `headers`. Thanks!